# what cause vue.js memory leak

Tags: vue.js, browser, memory-leaks

Memory leakage occurs in the browser with less memory (448MB). The chrome debugger was used to determine the cause, and the graph of the test is as shown in the image below. It has been confirmed that JS Heap, Nodes, and EventHandler are all reduced at the time of GC. Can the increase in Nodes and EventHandler also cause memory leakage?

Unfortunately, we can't allocate more memory...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The increase in nodes will increase the DOM elements therefore will contribute to the memory leakage. In addition to that there are also other factors that could be a cause for the memory leakage. Please check the below link to get to know the ways how to fix those problems
https://nolanlawson.com/2020/02/19/fixing-memory-leaks-in-web-applications/